# Filter a String based on the positions of each of its Characters?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I'm working on a Japanese Dictionary App, and I'm trying to match the Kanji (Typed on a SearchBar) with my Dictionary Data.

To give you some context, in order to match **集めた**(Typed on SearchBar) with **集める**(Dictionary Data), as you can see the grammar transforms the words slightly so it's hard to match them. So my plan has been to:

- Match the word in its entirety [Done]
- Match words based on first letter [Done]
- Match Words based on first + Second, the first+second, then first + second + third..

Is there any way I can achieve this. Thanks in Advance!

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            FilterDictionary = []

            FilterDictionary += Dictionary.filter { $0.k_ele["keb"]!.contains(text) }.compactMap { $0 }
            
            FilterDictionary += Dictionary.filter({ $0.k_ele["keb"]!.contains(where: { $0.hasPrefix(String(text.first ?? " "))
            })}).compactMap{$0}
            
        
            print(FilterDictionary)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: You can construct a array of first, first + second, etc. and filter on it. A regex too might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an extension over a collection of strings that will iterate through all possible prefixes of the search term, starting with the search term itself:

```swift
extension Collection where Element: StringProtocol {
    func matches<S: StringProtocol>(for search: S) -> [Element] {
        // go over all possible prefixes, the most lengthy ones being first
        // 0 means the exact word, 1..count are the rest
        (0..<search.count).reduce(into: []) { results, offset in
            let partialSearch = search.dropLast(offset)
            results += filter { $0.hasPrefix(partialSearch) && !results.contains($0) }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
myDictionary.values.matches(for: searchTerm)
```

The results will be in the decreasing order of matched characters: the ones that match the full search term will be first, the ones that match N-1 second, and so on. The last in the list will be ones that match only the first character, preceded by the ones that match the first two characters.

Comment: I ended up creating a function similar to yours when no one answered. Wish you saw this post earlier haha